# Use $/ file separator inside subroutine with opened file handle

Tags: perl, file, file-handling

I am having some problems with changing default file separator while iterating a file in Perl.

I have a previously opened file. I am storing its file handle in a variable. But I need iterate file using a custom delimiter.

The following doesn't work.

```
 sub iterate_custom {
    local $/ = "*****";
    my $fl_hdl = $prev_flhndl;
    while (my $data = <$fl_hdl>) {
        print $data;
    }
  }
```

Please say what is wrong in my code. Thx

Comment: What you posted is not sufficient to demonstrate your problem. Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. Also, please specify the behaviour you are observing and the behaviour you expect more clearly.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a very good way to describe your problem. To get the best and fastest answers, you should post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: To give you an example, here are a few things that could be "wrong" with your code. 1) your previous file handle has reached eof, or 2) has not been opened correctly, 3) is opened for writing, 4) does not exist because of a typo, 5) your file does not contain `****`, 6) you opened the wrong file, 7) the file does not exist, 8) you are in the wrong directory, 9) you are not calling the right subroutine because of a typo, 10) you are not passing the file handle to the sub correctly, 11) your code is actually working just fine, you just think it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong. It works just fine.

```
$ echo -n 'a*****b*****c*****' |  perl -e'
   my $prev_flhndl;

   sub iterate_custom {
      local $/ = "*****";
      my $fl_hdl = $prev_flhndl;
      while (my $data = <$fl_hdl>) {
         print "<$data>\n";
      }
   }

   $prev_flhndl = \*STDIN;
   iterate_custom();
'
<a*****>
<b*****>
<c*****>
```